# How can I convert percent into decimal?

Tags: java

Here is my code:
[image]

And this is the output. Why does it show "0.0" as value of `discount2`?

[image]

Comment: post the code rather then attaching an image

Comment: Change 100 to 100.0 so that Java will assume you want the final result in float instead of doing an explicit cast

Comment: Please read tutorial about data type, integer, double etc.

Comment: Please stop shouting. Thank you.

Comment: thank you guys, it works, thank you ecle

Answer (score -1):

discount2 is float.
So zero is 0.0
Change it into integer.

Comment: Nope, you've missed the point.

Comment: so how can i print the right answer?